# Failing to print current figure

Tags: animation, plot, octave

Here is an attempt of creating a simple animation by generating frames as a sequence of figures, saved in `.png` format<sup>1</sup>:

```
clc
clear
close all

% don't display plot : produces error.
%set(0, 'defaultfigurevisible', 'off');

% number of frames.
N = 2; 

% generate data sets.
x = linspace(0, 6 * pi, 1000);
y = sin(x);

% run animation.
for i = 1 : N

  % create figure.
  clf
  % hold on % produces error.
  plot(x, y, x(i), y(i), 'ro')
  % plot(x(i), y(i), 'ro') 

  grid on
  axis tight

  title( sprintf( 'Sine Wave at (%f, %f)', x(i), y(i) ) )
  xlabel('x')
  ylabel('y')

  drawnow 

  % create frame name: fr00001.png, etc. 
  framename = sprintf('output/fr%05d.png', i);

  % save current figure in file: output.
  print(framename);

end
```

However, the only thing I get is:

> Mesa warning: couldn't open dxtn.dll, software DXTn compression/decompression unavailable
> GL2PS error: Incorrect viewport (x=0, y=240883432, width=0, height=240885832)
> error: gl2ps_renderer::draw: gl2psBeginPage returned GL2PS_ERROR
> error: called from
> **opengl_print** at line 172 column 7
> print at line 519 column 14
> sinewave at line 48 column 3

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Note: the commented lines are intentionally left.

---

<sup>1. Later on to be stitched into a movie in `.avi` format with the help of an encoder.</sup>

## Executed on Octave-4.2.1 on Windows 10

Comment: Is the for loop relevant for your question? Please construct a [mcve]. Note that I'm not able to reproduce the error in MATLAB. This may be a GL2PS bug.

Comment: Your code tuns just fine in Octave 4.2.1 on my PC (Windows 7, using the GUI version of Octave). I just had to create the `output` directory, after that it was all good.

Comment: @am304 I have my `output` in the current working directory, but it does not get populated with any `.png` pictures, they just flash briefly on the screen and stop on the last one (when `N > 2`).

Comment: Which graphics toolkit are you using? I am using GNUPlot. Have you installed Ghostscript and is its directory on the Octave path?

Comment: @am304 Currently using (the default): `qt`. `fltk` and `gnuplot` available.

Comment: I would suggest you try with `gnuplot`, and make sure that Ghostscript is installed and on your Octave path. This is the code I use in my `.octaverc` file:
`cmd_path = getenv ("path");
gs_path = 'C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.19\bin';
if (isempty (strfind (cmd_path, gs_path)))
   setenv ('path', strcat (cmd_path, pathsep (), gs_path));
endif`

Comment: @am304 I have Gnuplot 5.0 patch 4 and when I tried to change `graphics_toolkit ('gnuplot')` I got `error: graphics_toolkit: gnuplot version too old.`, anyway, I got a message containing `GPL Ghostscript 9.16`, which shows that Ghostscript is available, no? Apologies for the comments, if requested I will add a summary of our discussion in the OP.

Comment: Try using this instead: `framename = sprintf('fr%05d', i);`  `print(framename,'-dpng');`

Comment: @SardarUsama I've tried all similar combinations: with / without extension, with / without parentheses around print - with format first and filename second, etc, mostly leading to crushes of Octave or merely displaying the plots, not saving them (along with multiple number of the same error message : `Current allocation mode is local GPL Ghostscript 9.16: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1`)

Comment: Suggested that since that works in MATLAB whereas your code doesn't. Anyway...

Comment: @SardarUsama I see, thanks, I'm tackling this issue for quite a while now, so any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: is there a file called dxtn.dll in your system?

Comment: To me this sounds like a DirectDraw / OpenGL installation issue. Maybe try updating your DirectX / OpenGL drivers? (also see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DirectDraw_Surface) and the related links)

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou DirectX version: 12; Graphics Card: latest (existing) updates.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou setting the figure invisible with a OpenGL based toolkits (FLTK and Qt) forces the use of OSMesa which doesn't work with 4.2.1 on windoze. The OP should either create the figures visible or use gnuplot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What helps<sup>1</sup> is to use `print()` with a graphics handle to the figure and to define the file names (`.png`) including the absolute path of the directory in which they will be stored. Noticing that sub-directory is denoted with `\` rather than `/`, moreover, it needs an additional `\` escape character to be valid. Then the following code:

```
N = 1000;
x = linspace(0, 6*pi, N);
y = sin(x);

abspath = 'D:\\...\\Project\\output\\';
fh = figure();

for i = 1 : N  
  clf
  hold on  
  plot(x, y);
  plot(x(i), y(i), 'ro')
  grid on
  axis tight
  title( sprintf( 'Sine Wave at (%f, %f)', x(i), y(i) ) )
  xlabel('x')
  ylabel('y')
  drawnow

  framename = sprintf('%sfr%04d.png', abspath, i);
  print(fh, framename);
end
```

produces 1000 frames, which when<sup>2</sup> stitched together give:

[image]

---

<sup>1. It still crashes unexpectedly after few hundred plots.</sup>

<sup>2. The first 100 `.png` files are converted to a `.gif` with the use of imagemagick's command: `magick convert -delay 10 -loop 0 *png output.gif`.</sup>

Comment: Proper Imagemagick command is convert for IM 6 and magick for IM 7. Do not combine the two. It may be crashing because your are loading all the frames into memory and creating an animation with the same number of frames, so the amount of memory needed is double and you may be running out of memory or tmp space.

Comment: @fmw42 Thanks for the remark! It is crashing on frame creation, i.e. within the Octave code.

Comment: @fmw42 I don't know either, so there are no _"unnecessary comments"_, nor need for apologies :)